# TFS getting all the files which was checked-in before a specific date

Tags: .net, tfs

I want to take source code of all the files which has been checked-in **before a specific day**.

e.g. If I have created a project 2 months ago and now it has 100 files, some files are added later. Then how can I take the original source code which was 15 days ago (It might contain less than 100 files because some files are added later).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Get Specific Version` command for this purpose. It depends on your version of Visual Studio where you can find this command. In previous versions, it was located in the context menu right under the `Get Latest` command. From VS2012 and above, it was moved to the Advanced sub-menu.

In the dialog, you can specify a point in time or various other methods (e.g. get by Label or ChangeSet). In your case, you specify by date and enter the point in time to get the files. Also, you choose whether you want to overwrite writeable files. It is advised to first clear your pending changes window either by checking, undoing or shelving in the changes.

If you want to open the project and work on them, running `Get Specific Version` to a point in time is usually enough.

However, if you want to assert that your workspace (or file system) contains only these files, you can follow this procedure (make sure that your workspace is clean before, so that you don't loose any valuable changes):

1. Get Specific Version to ChangeSet 1; this basically clears the subtree in your workspace.
2. Use Windows Explorer to delete left-over files and folders (e.g. Bin or Obj directories).
3. Get Specific Version to the point in time you want to get.

Afterwards, the file system will only contain the files that were checked in at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Get Specific version and select a date